# Can't access backend - 404 site not found

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, 404

I can't open the backend on my local project. The file **app/etc/local.xml** has this entry:

```
...
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[login]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
...
```

But if I enter http://project.local/login then I get 404 page not found.

What is going on?

Comment: try with `index.php` like this `http://project.local/index.php/login`

Comment: I already tried it, makes no difference

Comment: can you check is .htaccess file here or not in root ?

Comment: do you have store? have you tried with `http://project.local/admin/login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by executing this code:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

I actually had to change the table names, because I am using the prefix "mage" defined in **app/etc/local.xml**.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `magecore_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `magecore_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `magecore_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `magecustomer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Then I had to clear the cache by deleting the content in `/var/cache`

Solution found [here](http://www.keepaneye.de/bei-aufruf-magento-backend-fehler-404/).